# Find composite location on screen

Tags: java, swing, plugins, swt, awt

I am implementing a on screen keyboard in Java for SWT and AWT.
One important thing is to move the keyboard to a position where the selected text field can show and is not lying behind the on screen keyboard.

For AWT i can detect the position of the current selected component with

```
Component owner = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
if (owner == null) {
    return;
}
Point ownerLocation = owner.getLocationOnScreen();
Dimension ownerSize = owner.getSize();
```

How can i implement the same logic in SWT?
I get the current selected widget by adding a focuslistener to the SWT event queue. But when i call

```
Point location = new Point(mTextWidget.getLocation().x, mTextWidget.getLocation().y);
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(mTextWidget.getSize().x, mTextWidget.getSize().y);
```

I will get the position relativ to the parent composite.

How can i get the location of a special widget relativ to the complete screen?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the method [Control.toDisplay()](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/class-use/Point.html) should be able to translate your coordinates into ones relative to the screen.

This [snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg34321.html) may illustrate what you are after:

```
package org.eclipse.jface.snippets;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class Bla {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        final Text t = new Text(shell,SWT.BORDER);
        t.setBounds(new Rectangle(10,10,200,30));
        System.err.println(t.toDisplay(1, 1));

        Button b = new Button(shell,SWT.PUSH);
        b.setText("Show size");
        b.setBounds(new Rectangle(220,10,100,20));
        b.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                System.err.println(t.toDisplay(1, 1)); 
            }

        });

        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }

        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, buddy!  Your answer brought an end to a morning of pain.

Comment: works perfectly, thanks for bringing up toDisplay()! It will also accept a Point, which is handy when translating component locations.

I used it to translate event coordinates during a Drag&Drop session: composite.toDisplay(composite.getLocation())

Comment: @Gregor Nice to know this answer is still helpful... more than 5 years later.

Comment: @VonC: omg, didn't realise that;) well sadly SWT/RCP still lives on through RAP. I'm longing for JavaFX as a desktop/web client crossover framework though...

Comment: Words cannot do justice to how much I love you right now.