# SWT - get actual screen position of an image

Tags: java, swing, swt, awt

I have drawn an image on a Composite using the following code

```
imageCanvas = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);  

//adding paintListener to the canvas  
imageCanvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {  
@Override  
public void paintControl(PaintEvent e)  
{  
    if (sourceImage != null)  
    {  
        // draw the image   
        e.gc.drawImage(sourceImage, 120, 150);  

        //check the bounds of the image using the getBounds function  
        Rectangle newrec = sourceImage.getBounds();  
        System.out.println("X: " +newrec.x + " Y: "+newrec.y );    // prints (0, 0)      instead of (120, 150)  
    }  
}   
});
```

Now, I am trying to retrieve the image position on the screen. The image.getBounds function returns the bounds within the parent container and getLocationOnScreen() used in AWT/Swing is not available for SWT. How can I get the screen position of an image in SWT?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339821/find-composite-location-on-screen and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-swing2swt/section4.html. The IBM link is good if you are co-relating swing and and swt API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the display-relative coordinates.  If you have a Composite `imageCanvas`, and you're drawing an image on it at coordinates **120, 150**, then you can get the coordinates on the display by calling:

```
imageCanvas.toDisplay(120, 150);
```