# Get location of a widget to allow drawing a line from widget a to b

Tags: java, widget, swt

Hi I am working on adding a link between 2 classes on a class diagram to show their relation, the class diagram view allows for adding as many classes as the user wants. This is being done in SWT and the classes (which are a square button) are added dynamically using FormLayout and FormData, so I dont know the exact location of them.

The problem I am having is that when I try to get the location of the class (square button) via getLocation() it returns 0 for both x and y. This obviously means the drawLine() method doesn't draw anything.

I have looked into [To Display method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508589/swt-get-actual-screen-position-of-an-image?lq=1) 
However this just returns X and Y positions of the Classes which cant be correct such as e.g. (-757.451).

Any help or direction would be awesome, 
Thanks :D

Edit: heres a code snippet regarding my problem

```
    public void createClassButtons(Composite parent, Boolean pushDown) throws MalformedURLException, Exception
    {
        if(upButton == null || upButton.isDisposed() && !activePackageName.equals(""))
            {
                addUpButton(parent);

            }
        addNewClassButton(parent);

        final String[] classes = JavaModelHelper.getClassNames(activePackageName); //Get the class names 

        for(int i = 0; i < classes.length;i++) 
        {

            String entryString = classes[i];
            entryString = entryString.substring(0,entryString.lastIndexOf('.'));
            final int currentClassId = i; 
            Boolean createNew = true; 

            if(createNew)
            {
                classButtons.add(new ClassButton(parent,SWT.NONE,classes[i],i,activePackageName));
                classButtons.get(i).setText(entryString);
                classButtons.get(i).setMenu(buildMenuForClass(classes[i], classButtons.get(i)));

                //Position the button
                FormData buttonData = new FormData(90+(entryString.length() * 3),80);
                if(i-1 >= 0)
                {
                    buttonData.left = new FormAttachment(classButtons.get(i-1), 50, SWT.RIGHT);
                    buttonData.bottom = new FormAttachment(classButtons.get(i-1), 0, SWT.BOTTOM);
                    buttonData.top =  new FormAttachment(classButtons.get(i-1),0, SWT.TOP);
                }
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    buttonData.left = new FormAttachment(5);
                    buttonData.top = pushDown ?  new FormAttachment(25):new FormAttachment(15);
                }   

                classButtons.get(i).setLayoutData(buttonData);
                classButtons.get(i).getColor();
                checkSuperClass(classButtons.get(i),parent);

            }
        }
        parent.layout();
        parent.getShell().layout();
    }

    /*
     * Check Super Class - Checks if the class is inherited. 
     */
    void checkSuperClass(ClassButton b, Composite parent) throws Exception
    {
        Class<?> superClass = JavaModelHelper.getSuperclass(b.getMyClass()); 
        if(superClass != null)
        {
            for(ClassButton a:classButtons)
            {
                if(a.getMyClass().equals(superClass))
                {
                    drawInheritanceLink(b,a,parent);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Draw Inheritance Link - Draws an arrow tipped line between two given classes. 
     */
    void drawInheritanceLink(ClassButton a, ClassButton b, Composite parent)
    {
        GC gc = new GC(parent);
        gc.drawLine(a.getLocation().x, a.getLocation().y, b.getLocation().x, b.getLocation().y);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post [example code](http://sscce.org/) that shows the problem?

Comment: Have edited my post to show the code I am currently working with, decided to add the creation of the class button as it may help to my issue of getting the location of the class button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to draw the lines in `checkSuperClass` is called before the `parent.layout()`. Only layout computes the buttons' positions and this is why their location is still 0/0.

Apart from that, your drawing code will not update if the shell is resized or other reasons make it necessary to redraw the lines. Therefore you need to put all buttons within a `Canvas` widget and add an `SWT.Paint` listener to this widget. The paint listener is called whenever the canvas needs to be redrawn. Within the event handle ryou can then draw the connecting lines between the buttons.

```
canvas.addListener( SWT.Paint, new Listener() {
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    event.gc.drawLine( ... );
  }
} );
```

Furthermore I recommend reading [Creating Your Own Widgets using SWT](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm) to get a better undestanding of owner-drawn and custom widgets in SWT.

If your diagram has more complex requirements regarding layout and interaction with the diagram elements or even editing the diagram, you may also consider using [Draw2D](https://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/) or [GEF](https://eclipse.org/gef/) or [Graphiti](https://eclipse.org/graphiti/).

---